# multiple server block only 1 server block is loaded in mobile

Tags: nginx, dns, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

I am creating server block in sites-available nginx. I have 2 server name it works fine if access to browser but in mobile it will show the i.p address and it will load the first app, I cannot load the my second app because If I dial in url mysecondsubdomain.mydomain.com it will redirect to i.p address and the first app will be serve.. I don't know why it behaves like this

**updated** : I noticed also in browser after few hours when I type mysecondsubdomain.mydomain.com i will be redirected to i.p adress and it will serve my first app

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

     root /var/www/banking/public/;
     index index.php index.html index.htm;
     server_name banking.mydomain.com;

    location / {

         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri /index.php =404;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;    
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}  


 server {
          listen 80;
          listen [::]:80;


          root /var/www/inventory/public/;

          index index.php index.html index.htm;

          server_name inventory.mydomain.com;

          location / {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
          }


        location ~ \.php$ {
              try_files $uri /index.php =404;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;   
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              include fastcgi_params;   
             }
     }
```